# Can I use one local git repo as client/server?

Tags: git

We have git repo remotely located and local connection is very slow. Syncing 1 GB of data for every user is a painful job. Is it possible to setup one git locally to which all local users can sync and this one local repo can periodically sync with remote repo? Can some one tell me if it is possible to do? and if it is possible, how to do? Any links?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [gitolite](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Gitolite) to manage user accounts specifically for use with git.

[cgit](http://git.zx2c4.com/cgit/) is a simple, nice webUI for git repositories that does not depend on PHP.

If you want a full-fledged **GitHub/BitBucket/GoogleCode** localized setup then use [gitlab](http://gitlab.org/)

It's worth knowing that each git repo is self-contained so you just need to set the [ref to the host](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html) you desire.

If it's that much for an initial pull per user, just host a **clean copy of the git repo** on your LAN and new users can copy that via FTP/SCP/HTTP and then simply `pull` to the latest.

Answer (score 0):

**Preface**

You have badly designed repository layout or workflow (or both): 1G of data-exchange for every pull|push is **crazy nightmare**, how you get it? Giant binary artifact, changing in every changeset?! Is it really needed?

**Face**

Yes, any and every git-repo can work as client and as server and have any amount of custom remotes, usable as targets for pull|push.

Read about [git remote](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html) command (and it's subcommands) and ["How do i create a remote repo to push?](https://superuser.com/questions/220067/how-do-i-create-a-remote-repo-to-push)" topic from "Related" section

Comment: Thanks Lazy Badger. I'm looking into the links. This is the first time I am working on git,I have never worked on git so all the concepts are new to me.